# Incomplete tail output from the same file in different containers in Kubernetes emptyDir volume

Tags: kubernetes, tail, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

To test if a file in a emptyDir Volume is synchronized between containers I used [tail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) to observe the same file in two containers, and I stumbled upon the following behavior:

Pod definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: fortune
spec:
  containers:
    - image: luksa/fortune
      name: html-generator
      volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /var/htdocs
    - image: nginx:alpine
      name: web-server
      volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          readOnly: true
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
  volumes:
    - name: html
      emptyDir: {}
```

Example was taken from the book *Kubernetes in Action* by Marko Luksa. The `luksa/fortune` image just writes a [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)) text to the file `/var/htdocs/index.html` inside the `html-generator` container. Every 10 seconds a new file is written in which the content is the output of `fortune`.

Tailing the same file in both containers outputs **sometimes** an incomplete response by the `web-server` container.

Part of the `html-generator` container output:

`kubectl exec -c html-generator -it fortune -- tail -f /var/htdocs/index.html`

```
The very ink with which all history is written is merely fluid prejudice.
                -- Mark Twain
```

Part of the `web-server` container output

`kubectl exec -c web-server -it fortune -- tail -f /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

```
h all history is written is merely fluid prejudice.
                -- Mark Twain
```

**Question**: is this caused by

1. tail
2. slow IO speed of the node disk
3. Kubernetes volume sync logic
4. something else?

PS.: I also noted that cURLing the web-service pod port while the index.html is being written to causes nginx to return an empty response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with incomplete output from the container is caused by `nginx alpine` used in pod definition.
When you change the image from `nginx:alpine` to `nginx` the issue disappears because of different tail binaries used in those images.

Kubernetes volumes sync seems unlikely to cause the issue- as written in `emptyDir` [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)

> By default, `emptyDir` volumes are stored on whatever medium is
>   backing the node - that might be disk or SSD or network storage,
>   depending on your environment.

The [partition created by emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#local-ephemeral-storage) is ephemeral and applications cannot expect any performance SLAs (Disk IOPS for example) from this partition so "2. slow IO speed of the node disk" can also cause such issue but based on reproduction and changing image (what seemed to solve the issue) might be excluded.